# Open link in a side pane/frame?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to be able to click on "My Work" and have it open on the same page but only on the right half of the page, while everything on the left stays the same.  Basically the page splits in two once someone clicks "My Work".  I'm sure this is a juvenile question but I am lost and just beginning my journey.  I have found some JavaScript but I could not get it to work.  I believe the file was Split.js.

```css
h1 {
    font-family: "Fira Sans";
    font-style: bold;
    font-size: 40px;
    color:lightgray;
}

body {
    background-color:black;
    font-family: "Fira Sans";
}

#nav {
    color:lightgray;
}

#nav a{
    width:150px;
}

#img{
    opacity:0.85;
    position:absolute;
}

a {
    font-family: "Fira Sans";
    font-size: 20px;
    color:lightgray;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    color:white;
}

#footer{
    padding: 20px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    margin-left: 65px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Designs by RM</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
      <script src="split.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   </head>
    <h1>Ryan Manthey</h1>
   <body>
      
       

<div id="nav">
       <a href="designs.html">My Work</a>
</div>


       
       

       
       
<div id="img">
    <img src="ferris_wheel.jpg" alt="ferris wheel" width="700" height="600">
</div>  
       
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just an idea, have you looked into using an iframe, to accomplish this.

Comment: Yes I tried iframe and i didn't get it to work... but i tried again   (misspelling) and it worked.  Was just getting on here to mark the question solved.  Thank you for the reply.